# .NET 6 Problem: Bearer error="invalid_token"

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt

I am building an API with .NET 6 but I am stuck with this error. I get a token with login then I added that token to header but there is always getting 401: Unauthorized error.

NOTE: I am getting Bearer error="invalid_token" but **there is no description**.

This is my code;

Program.cs:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Business.DependencyResolvers.Autofac;
using Core.Utilities.Security.Encryption;
using Core.Utilities.Security.Jwt;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Autofac
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule()));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "OzkanOner", Version = "v1" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."

    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});

//CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
});

var tokenOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
        ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Authentication & Authorization
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

JwtHelper.cs:

```
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using Core.Extensions;
using Core.Utilities.Security.Encryption;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Utilities.Security.Jwt
{
    public class JwtHelper : ITokenHelper
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private TokenOptions _tokenOptions;
        private DateTime _accessTokenExpiration;
        public JwtHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

        }
        public AccessToken CreateToken(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            _accessTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.AccessTokenExpiration);
            var securityKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(_tokenOptions.SecurityKey);
            var signingCredentials = SigningCredentialsHelper.CreateSigningCredentials(securityKey);
            var jwt = CreateJwtSecurityToken(_tokenOptions, user, signingCredentials, operationClaims);
            var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

            return new AccessToken
            {
                Token = token,
                Expiration = _accessTokenExpiration
            };
        }

        public JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtSecurityToken(TokenOptions tokenOptions, User user,
            SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: tokenOptions.Issuer,
                audience: tokenOptions.Audience,
                expires: _accessTokenExpiration,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                claims: SetClaims(user, operationClaims),
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials
            );
            return jwt;
        }

        private IEnumerable<Claim> SetClaims(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.AddNameIdentifier(user.Id.ToString());
            claims.AddEmail(user.Email);
            claims.AddName($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}");
            claims.AddRoles(operationClaims.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray());

            return claims;
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "TokenOptions": {
    "Audience": "https://localhost:7047",
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:7047",
    "AccessTokenExpiration": 60,
    "SecurityKey": "ASD89ays7fhHASDF09ua0sdu6d32ghbjlka"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: I am on the same boat. First time trying dotnet 6, and after 7 different tutorials, the token validation still doesn't work.

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I was missing **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** nuget package.

Everything compiles and run Ok but throws invalid token while testing the api.
Once installed System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt it started working without changing a line of code.

Comment: I was so frustrated with the issue... but I applied your advice and wow it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help someone! Thats why I added this answer to an old thread.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I wasted many hours trying to solve this problem!

Comment: No way! This was actually it! Thank you. Very difficult to figure out this one.

Comment: I skimmed this article 3 times before finally trying this and it worked.

Comment: For us it was an old reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens v6.27.0 while v6.28.0 was working fine.

Comment: What in the hell is this even. Its a shame for the microsoft to leave this bug out there for people to figure out.

Comment: got this with Dotnet Core 7.0.384 , installing System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Worked

Comment: This is just insane, how the hell did you figure that out, ive been tearing my hair out for days. Thank you! Unreal

Comment: Wow, this saved my day, thanks! .NET should be more obvious.

Comment: Spent 2 days looking for this... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Program.cs Change:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"12345abcdef\""

});



builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
            };
});
```

It works fine using net 6. Download an example at https://drive.google.com/file/d/16VYtX5klxJF1jlnM4nFbz1rFPyCz-TZL/view?usp=sharing , use url:  /swagger

Answer (score 0):

In case of .Net 6, getting right version of nuget package is important. Try with these version of packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.15.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.0" />
```

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same issue in loosely following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/authenticate-and-authorize-apis-in-dotnet5/) tutorial (though I had upgraded to .NET 6). I found two solutions:

1. Downgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 5
2. Keep .NET 6 and when creating the JWT Token to return to the user, sign it using the HmacSha256*Signature* algorithm, rather than the HmacSha256 algorithm

In looking over [this](https://bytelanguage.net/2021/07/30/net-6-jwt-authentication-in-minimal-web-api/) tutorial that targets .NET 6, I noticed the different signing algorithm. I suspect v6.0 has incompatibilities.

You have a couple helper classes that you haven't included in your question, nor am I an auth wizard yet, so I can't say 100% what the issue is for you. Given my experience, I suspect the issue would be in your `SigningCredentialsHelper.CreateSigningCredentials` method.

This would have been a comment on your post rather than a non-authoritative answer, but I don't have the rep to do that.